# wrapper class to detect OS on a remote machine using webdriver?

Tags: java, javascript, frameworks, webdriver

Folks,

I want to write a wrapper class for my webdriver framework which will detect the connected client's OS on the go, so that I can  send proper format that machine understands. Can you help me on this?

java or javascript will help!
Love,
BijoyM

Comment: What clients do you expect your framework to have? What would be different about the format of response you send back?

Comment: I just need a simple wrapper, before I send my webdriver script to remote machine to check what OS it is using?

Comment: So you want to find out what OS the Selenium Server is running on?

Comment: Given **A** the machine the client runs on, **B** the machine the framework runs on, **C** the machine selenium server runs on and **D** the machine the website runs on: Which of those machines are the same machine? Which machine do you want to know the OS of? Which machine do you want to pass that information to?

Comment: I'm not worried about B, C could be same machine I need OS details of A/D

Comment: Why do you care about the OS of machine A? Shouldn't use send data back from the framework in a standard data format? Surely it is the responsibility of the client to convert it to a format for consumption (especially because people writing clients might want it in different formats for different circumstances).

Comment: Why do you care about the OS of the server hosting the website? Browsers can't make that distinction. The website just talks standard data formats over HTTP.

Comment: If you can run any code on client, what is wrong with `System.getProperty("os.name");  System.getProperty("os.arch"); System.getProperty("os.version");`?

Answer (score 0):

We use this client side sniffer: http://tim.dobbelaere.org/client_sniffer.html
All oyu need to do to have the js variables ready to read is to include the script on your page.

It might be godd practice to check for a browser/OS on a login page and save the info in a global server variable for further use.

Comment: That (if you modify the website to include it) will tell you the OS that the machine Selenium Server is running on. In the comments on the question @BijoyMeethal said he did not want that information (concerned only with the OS of the machine connecting to the framework and the machine hosting the website).

Comment: It is also hideously out of date. The last update was in 2004. Plenty of new browsers and operating systems have been released in the last 8 years.

Comment: hmm, we have a somewhat never version here - i will have to check

Answer (score 0):

`driver.desired_capabilities` or `driver.capabilities` (`desired_capabilities` is deprecated in newer versions of Selenium) dictionary has key "platformName" (or in older versions "platform"), which will have value "mac", "windows" or "linux" depending on the machine your Selenium node is running.